# Permissions for WSO2 Console User to Create and Manage Users?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using wso2 IS 5.11 and I would like to give some users the ability to log into the WSO2 console and manage users, but nothing else.  I've been trying to do this by setting permissions on a role.

By creating a role with the following permissions, I am very close to what I need:

- Admin Permissions/Login
- Admin Permissions/Configure/Security/Identity Management/Profile Management
- Admin Permissions/Manage/Identity/User Role UI Management/UI-Create
- Admin Permissions/Manage/Identity/User Management (Update, Create, List, View, Delete)
- Admin Permissions/Manage/Identity/Role Management (View, Update)
- Admin Permissions/Manage/Identity/User Profile Management (View, Create, Delete, Update)

However, a user with this role can grant any user the built-in admin role, and that's a problem.  I want this user to be able to manage application users, not to be able to make himself (or anybody else) a super user in the identity server.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Do you want to update the user roles that you create with the `less privileged admin` user accounts, or do you only need it to create `internal/everyone` role users?

Comment: The role I'm trying to create won't be able to create roles at all-- just create users and assign them roles that were created previously by a real admin.